# Stop form data being remembered

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I have an android app, and i open webViews within it.  now if someone types something into a textbox within my webView, the next time it is opened, it shows the suggestions (what the previous user typed).

How can i stop my webViews from storing the previous users entries?

The only way i can get rid of them is to delete all the data from my app, but i store other things in here, so dont want to delete all the data for my app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: see below answer will work it will disable form data to remember..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
```

here is full explanation

http://roysutton.com/2012/02/21/preventing-auto-fill-in-android-webview/